# How can I make Requests library work identical to file_get_contents?

Tags: php, curl, python-requests, libraries, file-get-contents

I am using https://requests.ryanmccue.info/ for my PHP requests and it is not working for one specific request to a Roblox API.

My **Requests** code (not working):

```
<?php
require_once "src/Autoload.php";
WpOrg\Requests\Autoload::register();
$request = WpOrg\Requests\Requests::get("https://games.roblox.com/v1/games/list?sortToken=T638231628258597209_Curated,R,H_a79d");
echo $request->body;
?>
```

My **file_get_contents** code (working):

```
<?php
$body = file_get_contents("https://games.roblox.com/v1/games/list?sortToken=T638231628258597209_Curated,R,H_a79d");
echo $body;
?>
```

How can I revise the **Requests** code to work **identical** to the file_get_contents code which is currently working for me?

Comment: Can you give more details of what is "working" and "not working" - are you getting error messages? A different response?

Comment: @IMSoP {"errors":[{"code":400,"message":"sortToken token is invalid","field":"sortToken"}]}

Comment: Perhaps you should properly URL-encode the parameter value, instead of relying on it happening automatically "under the hood" somewhere.